# Question of a formulaic irregularity in the korbanos reading of the morning service

Tags: tefilla, grammar-dikduk, shacharis-morning-prayer, korbanos-ketores-prayers

In the korbanos reading of the morning service, they all begin with vayomer h' el moshe l'emor... except the ketores which skips l'emor, saying only vayomer h' el moshe kach lcha...

why?

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya! Consider registering your account to best utilise the site's features.

Answer (score 3):

The expression לאמר is normally understood to imply that the statement following has to be said over to others. See for example Ramban on Shemos 6 (10):

> אמרו המפרשים כי מלת לאמר בכל התורה לאמר לישראל
>
> The commentators say that the word  לאמר generally in the Torah means
>   that the  the statement following has to be said over to the Jewish
>   people.

Now the verse for the ketores says

> וַיֹּאמֶר ה' אֶל משֶׁה **קַח לְךָ** סַמִּים
>
> And the L-rd said to Moses: "Take for yourself aromatics, ...”

Take **for yourself** so Moshe did not have to tell this instruction (take aromatics) to anyone else. So therefore the verse does not contain the word לאמר .

Hat-tip to @kouty.

Comment: In Bamidbar 10:1-2 Hashem told Moshe to make trumpets. He used the same “Lecha” but there it says leimar. Furthermore, the mefarshim say that without the word leimar, Moshe wouldn’t of been allowed to repeat it since one can only repeat what he heard with express permission. So how could he of repeated the ketores if it didn’t say leimar?

Answer (score 3):

The [Meshech Chochma](https://www.sefaria.org/Meshekh_Chokhmah%2C_Ki_Tisa.6?lang=he) explains that the Ketores that Moshe made for the ימי המילואם did not have מעלה עשן while the ones made for the future did. Therefore it doesn’t say לאמר because this was just for him during this 7 days;

> ויאמר ד' אל משה כו' הנה בשמן המשחה כתיב לאמר אעפ"י שלא הוכשר רק בשמן שעשה משה לבד ובקטרת שהוא לדורות לא כתוב לאמר. ונראה דמעלה עשן היה צריך להיות בקטרת בכל יום כמו דכתיב באחרי כי בענן אראה על הכפורת וכסה ענן הקטרת ולא ימות כו', ובקטרת שהקטיר משה בז' ימי המלואים לא היה מעלה עשן, שעדיין לא נראה הכבוד על הכפרת שבכל יום הקימו ופרקו, ולא היה עליו רק קדושת במה כמו שכתבו תוספות בע"ז ל"ד לכן לא כתוב לאמר, היינו שלדורות יהיו צריכים מעלה עשן מה שלא הוזכר עכשיו. ועיין יומא דף נ"ג ובתוספות ישנים שם ובמל"מ ודו"ק